# Tailwind a max of two flex items per row

Tags: html, reactjs, flexbox, tailwind-css, responsive

I've the following items:

```
const items = ['2342', 'Jensen Huang', 'jensen@gmail.com', '$ 200', 'delivered','29 Aug 2022', 'View All of the items']
```

And it is rendered as such (it's like flex-auto):

```
<div class="border flex flex-wrap gap-4 justify-between">
  {items.map((item) => <p>{item}</p>)}
</div>
```

It gives the following

```
+-----------------------------------------+
|2342     Jensen Huang    jensen@gmail.com|
|$ 200     delivered           29 Aug 2022|
|View All of the items                    |
+-----------------------------------------+
```

but I want a maximum of two elements per row; like this:

```
+--------------------------------+
|2342                Jensen Huang|
|jensen@gmail.com           $ 200|     
|delivered            29 Aug 2022|
|View All of the items           |
+--------------------------------+
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `grid` and `grid-cols-2`.

```
<div class="border grid grid-cols-2 gap-4 justify-between">
  {items.map((item) => <p>{item}</p>)}
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I think something like this might be what you want?

```
<div class="border flex flex-wrap gap-4 justify-between">
<div>
    <p>2342</p>
    <p>jensen@gmail.com</p>
    <p>delivered</p>
    <p>View All of the items</p>
</div>
<div>
    <p>Jensen Huang</p>
    <p>₹ 200</p>
    <p>29 Aug 2022</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the comment; I've edited the question to be more specific for my use case; my bad. If possible can you please help me with the updated question.